# We need to keep [tabs] on this ambiguity

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag wiki for [tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabs) says

> A user interface pattern that allows for the display of multiple pages
>   or elements with a navigation reference above, below, or to the side
>   of the content. On clicking the navigation reference, one element is
>   made visible while others are toggled off. Often, the navigation
>   reference is color-coded in a manner to indicate that it is currently
>   visible.
>
> **This can also refers to the character tab. See this GitHub study about tab versus space.**

(Why someone would note this ambiguity and not ask about it on meta escapes me)

Should this be split up, or should one (or both!) of these meanings be eliminated?

Comment: I have difficulty imagining why a tag would need to exist for the character itself.

Comment: The logical solution to the ambiguity would be to have a [tab] tag for the character. (That used to exist; it has since been synonymized with [tabs].) But, like Collin said, characters don't need their own tag. I'd go one further, though: UI patterns don't need their own tags, either. No one is an expert on tabbed UIs (at least, not *programmers*; maybe over on [UX.SE]). It would be more appropriate to have separate tags corresponding to the names of popular tab control implementations.

Comment: I don't think [tabs] has a right to live. As it can't stand alone. There is no meaning without a context here, be it an operating system, a programming language, an application. So why not get rid of it all together?

Comment: Well, if you subscribe to Plato's theory of the forms, it can stand alone :) In seriousness, though, what is the makeup? From the first page, I see mostly questions about either UI framework tabs or browser tabs — should they be separated too? Interestingly, the question at the top of the list (at the time I looked) is about tab-delimited text files (to answer @CollinD's question) =P What would that tag be? Would it merge with some already existing tag? Does Stack Overflow have a system to prevent users from using nonspecific tags, and regardless, would affecting this one be worth it?

Comment: "Does Stack Overflow have a system to prevent users from using nonspecific tags, and regardless, would affecting this one be worth it?" @andlabs reputation. Thing is that most people thinks that tags are hashtags.

Comment: [spaces] [should](https://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html) be used instead.

Comment: No space for [tabs] on SO

Comment: I'd suggest "Smoke [tabs]", but that's a little too British to be widely understood.

Comment: @kjhughes <twitch> that guy's method ("don't write tab-characters to disk, convert to spaces") is a one-way conversion that *forces* his number of spaces on other users viewing his files. By writing *tab-characters* instead, then different users can open the file and have those tabs be displayed at the desired width. (At least, for code indentation.) Talk about not wading into a religious war, yeesh.